# How to escape characters in Powershell

Tags: powershell, url, cmd, command-prompt

I am using below command to test the URL and same is used in monitoring tool.

```
cmd \c powershell -command "Invoke-WebRequest http://V2-LBDAX-PRD01:8101/DynamicsAx/Services/AxManageabilityServiceGroup" | findstr /c:"200 OK"
cmd \c powershell -command "Invoke-WebRequest http://V2-LBDAX-PRD01:8101/DynamicsAx/Services/BIServices" | findstr /c:"200 OK"
cmd \c powershell -command "Invoke-WebRequest http://V2-LBDAX-PRD01:8101/DynamicsAx/Services/CARDIXFServiceGroup" | findstr /c:"200 OK"
cmd \c powershell -command "Invoke-WebRequest http://V2-LBDAX-PRD01:8101/DynamicsAx/Services/CARItemStorePriceAvailServiceGroup" | findstr /c:"200 OK"
```

First and second command works, but the third and fourth command doesn't works. How do i escape /C. All url's having /C,i am getting error as below

'ARDIXFServiceGroup' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: It's `cmd /c`but not `cmd \c`!

Answer (score 1):

If you need to encode just the url, you can use `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` Method

```
[System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode("http://V2-LBDAX-PRD01:8101/DynamicsAx/Services/BIServices")
```

then replace the output with your current url,

Also you can use the `Powershell -EncodedCommand` to encode the whole command, also you can convert the `findstr /c:"200 OK"` to Powershell cmdlet `Select-String` so:

```
# Encode the Command First:
$command = 'Invoke-WebRequest http://V2-LBDAX-PRD01:8101/DynamicsAx/Services/BIServices | Select-String "200 OK"'
$bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($command)
$encodedCommand = [Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)
cmd /c powershell -encodedCommand $encodedCommand
```

Comment: You could also just check the StatusCode property instead of parsing a string. Something like:  
(Invoke-WebRequest http://google.com | select -ExpandProperty StatusCode) -eq 200